# Get data from more than one AsyncTask in one class?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

My situation is this:
first I call first AsyncTask which fetched required Items from database. After that, I call another AsyncTask, which fetches these Item images.

I am getting data from AsynTasks by using callback.

Here is the issue - since I am using callback, in my class I have method `processFinish` which returns AsyncTask data when it finishes its computation. The problem is with two Async tasks which depend on each other. What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the get() method of asyncTask that will wait for the output and wont proceed further
also you can use it with a timeout.

ex   `new BackgroundTask().execute.get();`

or

```
new BackgroundTask.execute.get(long timeout);
```

Comment: As I mentioned, this method is not recommended since .get locks UI.

Answer (score 0):

You could execute one AsyncTask inside another, but you should do it inside onPostExecute() because this method runs on the UI thread.

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
        new AsyncTask2.execute(..); // Start second task once you've got first results
    }
```

And you call your method `processFinish(..)` only once, after the second AsyncTask is completed.

Anyway, is there a reason why you use two AsyncTasks ? With your explanations we could believe that you might be able to use only one task.